# Passar query MySql para Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tenho uma query que ao passar para o eloquent me retorna erro de sintaxe.

```
SELECT order_id FROM timelines
WHERE order_id NOT IN (SELECT order_id FROM timelines WHERE supplier_approved_id) AND supplier_id = 2
GROUP BY order_id
```

Eloquent:

```
Timeline::select('order_id')
    ->whereRaw('order_id NOT IN', [], '( SELECT order_id FROM timelines WHERE supplier_approved_id )')
    ->where('supplier_id', 2)
    ->groupBy('order_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Em vez do get utilize o toSql() no Eloquente, isso vai retornar o SQL montado pelo Eloquente, ai você compara com sua query acima e vê o que tem de errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posso estar errado mas creio que o erro está em seu `whereRaw`. Tente sem a separação do array, como abaixo:

`->whereRaw('order_id NOT IN (SELECT order_id FROM timelines WHERE supplier_approved_id )')`

Comment: Podia jurar que havia tentado isso. Deu certo, obrigado.